# Theme licensing and permission on changing content

Tags: customization, themes, licensing

When using themes on a WordPress site, can I customize (I mean modify/change files) that makeup the theme? So as to remove a particular section on stock photo provided in the pages?

I like certain themes, but most of them include a footer, header, or something somewhere with extra information I would not want displayed, i.e.) theme name/version, developer link, etc.

Is it ok to remove those from displaying on the website?

Comment: This is a ''copyright'' question about third-party Themes, and not a question specific to ''WordPress''. Consult the license terms of the specific Theme in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is totally up to the theme, its author(s), and the licence that the theme should be accompanied by.

WordPress itself is published under [GPL(v2)](https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html). A huge amount of themes and plugins is too. Or at least a *similar* licence (e.g., [MIT](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)).

But in every case: What counts is what the product is *shipped* with.

Comment: So if the theme is under, License: GNU General Public License v2 or later ...it means I am free to modify it correct?

Comment: Of course you can modify the code in the theme. Its the redistribution that's in question depending on how its licensed.

Comment: I don't plan to distribute it, I just want to use it modified on a website. 

Thanks!